# monolog with different levels and environments

Tags: php, symfony

under app/config/config_dev.yml I have:

```
monolog:                                                                                                              
    handlers:                                                                                                         
        main:                                                                                                         
            type: stream                                                                                              
            path: /var/log/dev.log                                                                                     
            level: debug
```

and under  app/config/config_prod.yml I have:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        syslog:
            type: stream
            path: /var/log/prod.log
            level: error
```

In my controller I have

```
$logger = $this->get('logger');

$logger->debug("foo");
```

I would expect to see the debug entry while in dev and only error and above entry when in prod.

But so far it's outputting everything. How can I adjust it so that different levels exists for different environments?